# What's the operation for rotating a tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

In my case I need the following operation, for a `2x2` matrix (tensor):

```
a = [[1,2],
     [3,4]]
```

The output is `b=np.rot90(np.rot90(a))`

```
b = [[4,3],
     [2,1]]
```

Does anybody know this operation for this? `b = sess.run(tf.reverse(a,axis=-1))` seems not the one. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I know the operation `tf.contrib.image.rotate` as suggested by @jakeoung, but does this operation support the back-prorogation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.image.rotation` function. See:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1,2],
     [3,4]], dtype=tf.float32)
# a_ = tf.expand_dims(a, 2)
# print(a_)
b = tf.contrib.image.rotate(tf.contrib.image.rotate(a, 90), 90)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  [rot] = sess.run([b])
  print(rot)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know this operation, but does this operation support the back-propagation?

Comment: @mining, yes definitely it supports.